# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySAGA'

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu, saga

I am trying to install the SAGA GIS python bindings on ubuntu 22.04. I have successfully installed SAGA on my computer and have it running on my QGIS install. However, when I try to import the python package, I can't import `from PySAGA import saga_api` and get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySAGA'`. I am trying to install SAGA GIS with my anaconda environment's python install too. I've followed these steps [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Linux/), though I tried a few different cmake flags to change the python inputs. Below is what I ran.

`cmake ../saga-gis -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/laserglaciers/anaconda3/envs/qgis/bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=/usr/local/lib -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/laserglaciers/anaconda3/envs/qgis/bin/ -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/laserglaciers/anaconda3/envs/qgis/bin/python -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/laserglaciers/anaconda3/envs/qgis/bin/python -DWITH_TRIANGLE=OFF -DWITH_SYSTEM_SVM=ON -DWITH_TOOLS_VIGRA=OFF -DWITH_DEV_TOOLS=ON -DSVM_INCLUDE=/usr/include/libsvm/svm.h`

Comment: Some clues here maybe?  https://pypi.org/project/PySAGA-cmd/1.0.1/